# seq_len not recognized in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm new to Rcpp, and this may be a silly question, but I can't seem to get seq_len to work in rcpp, even though I know it should be an [R-like function](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/210_rcpp_functions.html#vector-related-functions) that Rcpp has. This is my code:

```
cppFunction("NumericVector foo2(int n){
IntegerVector x = Rcpp::seq_len(n);
return x;
            }")
```

This results in the error message: "error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'Vector<13>' to function return type 'Vector<14>'
return x;"

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error message of some sort? So you get a value returned other than what you expect?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your previous question asked a few hours ago?  In other words, a more standard StackOverflow way would have been to edit / adjust your previous queston.

Comment: One good way to ensure your question is reproducible, fully understood, and responds well to searches ... is to include the full error message when you run this command. In this case, it's likely something like `error: could not convert 'x' from 'Vector<13,[...]>' to 'Vector<14,[...]>'` (pointing to `return x;`), due to the problem @AllanCameron fixed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback; I'm also new to StackOverflow, so still learning the ropes of how to ask good questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try your code, the compiler throws an error saying that an IntegerVector cannot be converted to a NumericVector in the output. However, a simple change to:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector foo2(int n){
IntegerVector x = Rcpp::seq_len(n);
return x;}")
```

Produces no errors and we get:

```r
foo2(3)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```